# What software needed to view this website?

Tags: 12.04, websites

I have installed OpenJDK on my 12.04. I wonder what software is needed to view [a virtual tour of an apartment](http://www.realestatedimensions.com/wymanTowers.html): http://www.realestatedimensions.com/VirtualTours/WymanTowers/?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you need to install the java plugin for your web navigator.

- If you use OpenJDK, try to install the [IcedTea plugin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/icedtea-plugin) : `sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin`

  Then, it will be available for all web browsers (firefox, chrome, chromium).
- If you use the JDK from Sun, it will be a little more complicated ([problem of licensing](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/JavaTeam), bless the Oracle lawyers :( ), because it is no more packaged for debian/ubuntu. You'll have to download the jdk directly from Oracle/Sun website and install it [as explained here](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java).

  If you have Google Chrome (or if you want to make the plugin available for all users), try something like this :

  ```
   ln -s /path/to/the/official/jre/lib/your_arch/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Just wonder if you also know about various common versions of Java and their corresponding java plugin for web browsers? Is there such a list?

Comment: @Tim : I updated my answer with the knowledge I have about the Sun/Oracle procedure.

Comment: Does a java plugin apply to several browsers, such as Firefox, Google Chromium?

Comment: @Tim : yes, once installed for Firefox, IcedTead is available for Chrome/Chromium, for the Sun version, you have to make a symbolic link.